Crop YUV_420_888 image without converting it into Bitmap
I am facing a problem where when I try to crop a YUV_420_888 image, it gets messed up on some devices (Samsung S22 Ultra) but not on others (Samsung A14). Here are the sample images:
First Image

Cropped Image

Here is my code that receives frames from camera. I am trying to crop each frame here.
override fun analyzeImageProxy(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

    val mediaImage = imageProxy.image

    if (mediaImage != null) {

        val bitmap = ImageConvertUtils.getInstance().getUpRightBitmap(InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, 0))

        println(bitmap) // AT THIS POINT, THE IMAGE IS FINE. SEE FIRST IMAGE.

        val croppedImageByteArray = cropYUV420(
            imageToByteArray(mediaImage),
            mediaImage.width,
            mediaImage.height,
            imageProxy.cropRect.left,
            imageProxy.cropRect.top,
            imageProxy.cropRect.width(),
            imageProxy.cropRect.height()
        )

        val inputImage = InputImage.fromByteArray(
            croppedImageByteArray,
            imageProxy.cropRect.width(),
            imageProxy.cropRect.height(),
            imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees,
            InputImage.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21
        )

        val bitmap2 = ImageConvertUtils.getInstance().getUpRightBitmap(inputImage)

        println(bitmap2) // AT THIS POINT, THE IMAGE IS MESSED UP. SEE CROPPED IMAGE.

        imageScanner.scanFrame(imageProxy, inputImage)
    }
}

Following is the code that is being used for cropping. I don't understand it completely, I just got it from some other answer here on SO.
private fun cropYUV420(
    yuvData: ByteArray,
    imageWidth: Int,
    imageHeight: Int,
    cropX: Int,
    cropY: Int,
    cropWidth: Int,
    cropHeight: Int
): ByteArray {

    val croppedYUV = ByteArray(cropWidth * cropHeight * 3 / 2)

    // Crop the Y plane
    for (row in 0 until cropHeight) {
        val srcPos = (cropY + row) * imageWidth + cropX
        val destPos = row * cropWidth
        System.arraycopy(yuvData, srcPos, croppedYUV, destPos, cropWidth)
    }

    // Calculate the starting point for the UV planes
    val uvHeight = imageHeight / 2
    val uvCropHeight = cropHeight / 2
    val uvImageWidth = imageWidth / 2
    val uvCropWidth = cropWidth / 2
    val uStart = imageWidth * imageHeight
    val vStart = uStart + (uvHeight * uvImageWidth)

    // Crop the U plane
    for (row in 0 until uvCropHeight) {
        val srcPos = uStart + (cropY / 2 + row) * uvImageWidth + cropX / 2
        val destPos = cropWidth * cropHeight + row * uvCropWidth
        System.arraycopy(yuvData, srcPos, croppedYUV, destPos, uvCropWidth)
    }

    // Crop the V plane
    for (row in 0 until uvCropHeight) {
        val srcPos = vStart + (cropY / 2 + row) * uvImageWidth + cropX / 2
        val destPos = cropWidth * cropHeight + uvCropHeight * uvCropWidth + row * uvCropWidth
        System.arraycopy(yuvData, srcPos, croppedYUV, destPos, uvCropWidth)
    }

    return croppedYUV
}

private fun imageToByteArray(image: Image): ByteArray {

    val yBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer // Y
    val uBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer // U
    val vBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer // V

    val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
    val uSize = uBuffer.remaining()
    val vSize = vBuffer.remaining()

    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)

    // U and V are swapped in the YUV 420 format
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize)
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize)

    return nv21
}

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Please narrow it down: Is the problem in cropYUV420, InputImage.fromByteArray or getUpRightBitmap? Use the same image on both devices and check when the content starts to differ.

The problem is in cropYUV420 function. I have verified that before asking the question. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

I see, thanks. Is there a reason why you use System.arraycopy instead of yuvData.copyInto? Although I do not see how that would affect your current problem, it would still be the better choice because you gain type safety, you can use parameter names and you could even use other compilation targets than the JVM if you would want to some day.

@Leviathan There is no reason for using System.arraycopy instead of yuvData.copyInto. As mentioned above, I copied this functionality from somewhere else.
